# What are the multi-touch netbooks/tablets that work with Ubuntu?

Tags: tablet, ubuntu-netbook, multi-touch

I will be going to University soon and am looking for a tablet/netbook on which I can use a stylus to write notes (Chinese characters mostly).  I have only found 2 netbooks (with swivel screens and full keyboards) that might work for me.  One is the ASUS Eee PC T101MT, and the other is a Gigabyte Touchnote.

Does anyone know of tablets (keyboardless) that Ubuntu fully works on?

Comment: You should remove netbook from your question altogether. Not the word you're looking for.

Comment: There are 2 different types of computers that will work for me.  A netbook with a multi-touch screen and a tablet.  This is why I have the tablet/netbook in the question.

Comment: Likely he is adding `netbook` because he wants something portable and within the budget of someone living in that region.

Comment: Multi-touch is not a necessary component of capacitive handwriting capture.  There have been capacitive touch- and/or pen-capture devices for a long time, but multi-touch in main-stream operating systems is fairly new.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 5):

Please see this to get help with MultiTouch in Ubuntu: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch#Community%20Help

The same page has a section dedicated to devices currently supported or being tested by the community. Your two choices don't seem listed there but I'd encourage you to file bugs:
ubuntu-bug utouch

If you can do so from any of the devices, within a 10.10 live CD, that would be best.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Touchbook](http://www.alwaysinnovating.com/touchbook/).

Comment: Looks interesting.  I'll have to keep my eye on this one.

Comment: Right now they are not shipping any units because they are working on their latest innovation.  So I'm not sure if I will have time to wait for this one.

Answer (score 2):

I currently use a Lenovo X61 Tablet pc with Xournal as my handwritten notes application.  There was some custom configuration I had to do, but for the most part it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well Ubuntu is working on multitouch and it should be in either the next release or the release after. Synaptics is making it too but I dont know if thats ready yet.

The touch screens will work it will just move the mouse to the place you touch it just wont do anything special.

Comment: I had some basic multitouch functionality with my standard Synaptics laptop touchpad awhile back. Nothing special, just two-fingered scrolling that didn't work all that well anyway.

Comment: Macbooks aren't supported by the Canonical work yet.  Instead, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/9460/is-it-possible-to-get-dragging-working-on-a-macbook-multi-touch-touch-pad/26198#26198 for support for the basics (dragging, scroll, etc).