# Macbook Pro touchpad

Tags: touchpad, macbook-pro

Just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Macbook Pro 7.1 model. It's working great, but I can't get used to the reduced functionality of the touchpad.

I've read that mtrack works pretty well at bringing that functionality back. However, I'm having a hard time installing it. All I can find is the source course from the git repository: [xf86-input-mtrack](https://github.com/BlueDragonX/xf86-input-mtrack)

How and what do I need to do to either install this driver or just get the touchpad back to normal?

EDIT: Found this answer here, and it works pretty well: [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/103030/53851)

Comment: How well does it work? I have run into many dead ends, and finally got back to sanity (although not as awesome as the standard Apple trackpad support) on my MacBook with Ubuntu. For me the default is what worked the best.

Comment: It works pretty well in the sense that I can now click and drag without having to double tap. It still doesn't let me rest my thumb on the bottom of the trackpad, but I found that if I hardware clicked on something then without removing my thumb started to use move the mouse with my finger it would let me keep my thumb in the same place.

While not ideal, it's still better than what I had before.