# Does the touch interface on new Windows 8 computers work in Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, hardware, touchscreen

I'm a new linux/Ubuntu user. I realize that [multitouch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128/what-are-the-multi-touch-netbooks-tablets-that-work-with-ubuntu) exists for touchpads, but are touch screens supported?

Comment: Sure, Ubuntu is more powerful than Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it has a touch interface, it will be supported by Unity. But you'll have to check the hardware compatibility (drivers,etc).

But don't be "afraid" by the touch screen.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I would prefer to be "excited" and wasn't planning to be afraid. How do I go about determining what drivers to get and how to install them?

Comment: Start by getting the hardware specifications (models of composants, constructors,etc) and a simple Google search will be fine. And by afraid, I meant afraid by compatibility problems ;)